# Data sync between Linked Server and Local server using Merge when table structure is different (SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have a **linked server** and **Test Db** under my localDb Server (SQL 2014).

A linked server has a table:

```
Valid State(StateId(char Pk), Name, Desc, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy)
```

Inside my Test Db I have a table:

```
Valid State(Id(int PK),Abbreviation(char) ,Name, IsActive)
```

I need to sync the data between these linked server and my table. What would be the approach to deal with the situation where I can implement SQL- Merge. 
I got some idea from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66066/

I get to the point where the query works if, the table structures are SAME. But the situation is different where structure are different. Any suggestions will be appreciated :)
Thank you !

Comment: Can you provide an example of a scenario where the structure is not the same?

Comment: I am using this for Data Sync between 2 different servers, (must use linked server --some reasons ). Not sure if i made is easier

Comment: Try this: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/  Show a table structure with sample data on both servers and what you have tried - this way we can help you with the errors/issues which you're encountering

Comment: It all depends on how they are to be synchronised i.e. what value should be placed in IsActive? Define the rules first (on paper) and then code them.

Comment: Sorry @Eli , I couldnt get the tables and my work listed here, Its saying too many characters. Do we have alternative to get the code being displayed here?

Comment: @Alex , Sync will be made probably once in a week or so, We have Static Tables( includes static data). The new columns will have auto generated values / computed values

Comment: Are you saying IsActive is autogenerated? Please be specific. Also be specific about your merge rules. (When is data inserted, updated or deleted?) If there is an id in the test db that isn't in the linked  server, do you want to delete it? You need to be specific, and that includes error messages.

Comment: @PinkZen - you have to appreciate the fact that we have very limited information (only what you have provided in the question) about your schema and requirements and we have no idea about what constitutes a  "new column". You need to narrow down your question to a specific problem and provide enough (but not too much) relevant information to explain it. I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Source_Valid_States Table
StateID | Name      | CreatedDate | LastUpdatedDate | IsActive |Latitude      AK        | Alaska     | 2017-08-29   | 2017-08-29           |        1     |      0.687     
CA        | California | 2017-08-29  | 2017-08-29            |       1     |      0.663

Comment: Target_Valid_States Table
|Id |Abbreviation |Name      |Latitude|SortId|IsActive | StartDate   |  EndDate|
| 1 | AA               | Armed .. | 61.38   |   0     |        0   | 1905-06-5 |1905-06-5 |  |2  | AK              | Alaska    | 61.38    |   0     |       0    | 1905-06-5 | 1905-6-5|
| 3 | CA              |California | 61.38   |  0     |        0    | 1905-06-5| 1905-06-5|

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've added Source&Target table,result would be of Target Table on the above 2 comments. IsActive would be computed/auto generated value. For Eg:new identity column Id will be auto gen(PK), StateId(char, PK)from Source tbl would map to Abbreviation in Target tbl,Name -->same, StartDate-->CreatedDate, EndDate ->LastUpdatedDate, IsActive is not present in Source Tbl -->so we'd have to insert auto computed value/or null.. ..   WHEN matched THEN  UPDATE -- WHEN not matched BY TARGET THEN INSERT -- no deletion.Extremely sorry if my question was unclear. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Alex, all I am trying to do is, if the data dont exists in Tgt tbl --insert, if data is changed --update / no need for deletion for now. we also need to map column 1 by 1 since column field name is different in Tgt & Src tbl. I am convinced to write dynamic sql query. I got into a point where i can perform merge for same tbl structure, not sure how to achieve for non-similar tbl structure.  Thank you for providing me guidelines for asking question. Hope this helps.

Comment: You do not need dynamic SQL. What would really be of value here is to put your examples in the question, don't scribble them in the comments. In your example, the structures aren't even different, the columns names are just different. Surely you an see how trivial it is to allow for this?

Comment: @PinkZen instead of sticking your table structure into the comments, you can edit your post and stick it in there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the id's between the systems actually match, this will do what you want:

```
-- Insert any new records
INSERT INTO [Valid State](Id,Name, IsActive)
SELECT StateId, Name 
FROM LinkedServer.database.schema.[Valid State] SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM [Valid State] TGT WHERE TGT.ID = SRC.StateID
    )


-- Update any existing records
UPDATE TGT
SET Name = SRC.Name
FROM [Valid State] TGT
INNER JOIN
LinkedServer.database.schema.[Valid State] SRC
ON SRC.StateID = TGT.ID
```

Even after all this prompting you haven' explained what you want to do with the leftover fields. So I've left them out

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to update first and then insert, so you don't waste time on updating an insert.